# How do I natively run linux on the Chromebook 15 (CB3-532)?

Tags: linux, bios, operating-systems, chromebook

After experimenting with ChromeOS and Crouton, I made the decision to transition my Acer Chromebook 15 (CB3-532) to run just Linux.
During my research I realized that I would need to:

- Enable Developer Mode
- Enable Read/Write
- Install a Modified BIOS

From this page referenced in other articles on this topic:
https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/
I searched through the Supported Models Matrix for the correct command to download and run a script, to flash the firmware with a SeaBIOS payload.
I noticed that the CB3-531 "Banjo" had firmware mods RW_LEGACY and BOOT_STUB available. However, I did not see the newer CB3-532 "Banon" listed for any options.

I would like to know if those commands are compatible for my device ?
Also, if there are alternative mechanisms to fully replace my Chrome OS.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated, I am a broke college student and would hate to go through my courses running Chrome.
As a novice programmer this is not too familiar territory for me but I love to learn new tricks.

Here are the sites I went through to attempt to execute this:

- https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/more-chromebook-fun-fully-replacing-chromeos-with-linux/56885
- https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-any-linux-distro-on-a-chromebook
- https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't answer your question but a good place to ask is https://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/.

Comment: Have you tried crouton?  It would probably be a reasonable alternative if this ends up not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Settings>Advanced>Developer and hit Turn On, it should start the process. Do note that unlike most systems, Chrostini does **not** come with a full desktop environment. Instead, you're supposed to rely on command-line. Also, do note that some things do take more work than if you simply ran Linux on bare metal. Finally, you may note that the DE that is present is GNOME, so installing `gnome-control-center`  using `apt` will help.

Hope this helps.

Mac Henni